# Move Element Position as Function of Width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to get the `iframe` below to move up to a relative negative position by an amount proportional to the width.

```
<iframe id="fullwidthvideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/uV33h4f1E1s?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=uV33h4f1E1s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('fullwidthvideo').onload = function() {
   vidElement = document.getElementById('fullwidthvideo');
   vidElement.style.top = vidElement.width * -0.25;
   }
</script>
```

This CSS to the `iframe` element works, so I'm just trying to figure out how to make it dynamic with JavaScript.

```
top: -200px;
```

I'm not sure what's happening because the JavaScript seems to be calculating a value of 0.  Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys were to use `element.clientWidth` and setting `element.style.top` to a string ending with an appropriate format specifier (e.g. 'px').

```
<iframe id="fullwidthvideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/uV33h4f1E1s?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=uV33h4f1E1s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('fullwidthvideo').onload = function() {
 vidElement = document.getElementById('fullwidthvideo');
 vidTop = vidElement.clientWidth * -0.25;
 vidElement.style.top = vidTop + 'px';
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line is causing the issue:

```
vidElement.style.top = vidElement.style.width * -0.25;
```

When dealing with iframes, I don't use style.width, but only width like so:

```
vidElement.style.top = vidElement.width * -0.25;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it's still calculating the `iframe` element top as 0px.